# menu with progress bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a menu like this site 
http://www.easywaytea.com.au/
not drop down part only the progress animation

this is what i am trying

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// box 1
$('#level2').mouseover(function(){
    $('#menu_progress').animate({width:"37%"});
});
$('#level2').mouseout(function(){
    $('#menu_progress').animate({width:"8%"});
});
```

});

```
<div class="menu_container">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="level1"><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li id="level2"><a href="current-promotions.html">Current Promotions</a></li>
            <li id="level3"><a href="our-drinks.html">Our Drinks</a></li>
            <li id="level4"><a href="faq.html">FAQ’s</a></li>
            <li id="level5"><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
            <li id="level6"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  <div id="menu_progress"></div>
  </div>
```

but problem is that when moving to the next menu item animation is repeating every time i hover a menu item
any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iseyoj/2)**

Its Include simple Jquery as:

```
$(function(){
  $(".navLinks").on("hover","a",function(){
    width =$(this).position().left +parseInt($(this).width());
    $(".thermo").animate({width: width}, {queue: false});
  });

});
```

======= Edit 1 ============

To role the progress bar back to normal position on mouseout
Just Add a mouse Out event

```
$(".navLinks").mouseout(function(){
  width =$(".navLinks .activeLink").position().left +parseInt($(".navLinks .activeLink").width());
  $(".thermo").animate({width: width}, {queue: false});
  });
```

See the **[DEMO2](http://jsbin.com/iseyoj/3)**

Comment: thanks for help but one issue how to role the progress bar back to normal position on mouse out.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an example:

```
$('.menu ul li').mouseover(function(){
    var x = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width();
    $('#menu_progress').animate({width:x});
});
```

with some CSS style:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EMMaj/)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have two jsfiddle examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/wmichaelgreen/Gj6Pv/

http://jsfiddle.net/xXM2z/

There you change the `width` with JQuery, too.
Maybe it will help you.